# Flat File Path Name Convention in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am working in SSIS under SQL Server 2008 R2.  I have a package that imports flat files into destination tables.  In the connection manager for the flat files, the import works fine if I use my mapped drive name in the file path (e.g., Z:\folder\file_name.txt).  However, it does not work if I use the UNC file path name (e.g., \\server_share\folder\file_name.txt).  How do I get around this?

Comment: Something is off in your usage. Using UNCs with file paths should produce no discernible results compared to a mapped drive - assuming you're using the same credentials.

Comment: I just tried finding the file in Windows.  If I use the mapped drive name, Windows can find it.  However, if I use the UNC path name, Windows can't find it.  So, I know this isn't unique to SSIS.  Something else is wrong.

Comment: I figured out my problem.  The UNC file path name was incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My UNC file path name was incomplete.  I found this out by running net use in a command prompt.